# QMargins in QSS

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

Is it possible to set a custom QMargins Q_PROPERTY via QSS? Does it follow the margins syntax? Maybe I missed something obvious, but I didn't find any specific reference for this usage.

Comment: loog at border / padding / margin QSS properties. There are everything clear in Qt documentation.

Comment: Look for a keyword `margin` here http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html

Answer (score 1):

It was already mentioned in the previous answer that there's no specific parsing method for QMargins, but the property data is set as QStringList so we can add converters to make QMargins variable accept QStringList object.

```
const char QCssCustomValue_Margin[] = "qmargins";

QStringList marginsToStringList(const QMargins &margins) {
    return {QLatin1String(QCssCustomValue_Margin), QString::asprintf("%dpx", margins.left()),
            QString::asprintf("%dpx", margins.top()), QString::asprintf("%dpx", margins.right()),
            QString::asprintf("%dpx", margins.bottom())};
}

QMargins stringListToMargins(const QStringList &stringList) {
    QMargins res;
    if (stringList.size() == 2 &&
        !stringList.front().compare(QLatin1String(QCssCustomValue_Margin), Qt::CaseInsensitive)) {
        QStringList valueList = stringList.back().split(",");
        QVector<int> x;
        for (int i = 0; i < qMin(valueList.size(), 4); ++i) {
            QString str = valueList.at(i).simplified();
            if (str.endsWith(QLatin1String("px"), Qt::CaseInsensitive)) {
                str.chop(2);
            }
            bool isNum;
            int num = str.toInt(&isNum);
            if (isNum) {
                x.push_back(num);
            } else {
                x.push_back(0);
            }
        }
        res.setLeft(x[0]);
        res.setTop(x[1]);
        res.setRight(x[2]);
        res.setBottom(x[3]);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Then you should register these two functions to QApplication, make sure the codes below run before the property is set when the stylesheet is loaded.

```
// Implement outside
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QMargins)

// Execute after QApplication is created
QMetaType::registerConverter<QStringList, QMargins>(stringListToMargins);
QMetaType::registerConverter<QMargins, QStringList>(marginsToStringList);
```

After such preparation, when you have a Q_PROPERTY like this in a custom widget,

```
Q_PROPERTY(QMargins margins READ margins WRITE setMargins NOTIFY marginsChanged)
```

you can add property in stylesheet like,

```
MyWidget {
    qproperty-margins: qmargins(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to remove any margins set by the layout. As far as I know you need to do this by code.

```
layout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
layout->setSpacing(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

In qcssparser.cpp (version 5.4) they have

```
    QVariant v;
    const QVariant value = w->property(property.toLatin1());
    switch (value.type()) {
    case QVariant::Icon: v = decl.iconValue(); break;
    case QVariant::Image: v = QImage(decl.uriValue()); break;
    case QVariant::Pixmap: v = QPixmap(decl.uriValue()); break;
    case QVariant::Rect: v = decl.rectValue(); break;
    case QVariant::Size: v = decl.sizeValue(); break;
    case QVariant::Color: v = decl.colorValue(); break;
    case QVariant::Brush: v = decl.brushValue(); break;
#ifndef QT_NO_SHORTCUT
    case QVariant::KeySequence: v = QKeySequence(decl.d->values.at(0).variant.toString()); break;
#endif
    default: v = decl.d->values.at(0).variant; break;
    }

    w->setProperty(property.toLatin1(), v);
```

So it's no special reader for margin.